# When accessed similarly, why does a SQLAlchemy relationship return differently?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

With this simplified model:

```
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # other attributes

    #user many-to-many size associations (using link tables)
    sz_shirt_dress_sleeve = db.relationship(
        'SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve',
        secondary=LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve,
        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    strange = {'whyisthisdifferent': db.relationship(
        'SizeKeyShirtDressNeck',
        secondary=LinkUserSizeShirtDressNeck,
        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))}
```

I would assume that I can use both of these to access the relationship, but it isn't so. See this interactive session:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> from app.models import User
>>> u1 = User.query.first()
>>> u1
<User id: 1, email: 'admin@admin.com', password_hash: 'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$n2qsqVfu$8d1bc6b0a472818175c21c1a31031ece58e78feca9c6d15a326b28bd7fd80e67'>
>>> u1.strange['whyisthisdifferent']
<RelationshipProperty at 0x106c6d248; no key>
>>> u1.sz_shirt_dress_sleeve
[Dress shirt sleeve size: 3000]
```

Why does accessing by `u1.sz_shirt_dress_sleeve` actually return the result of the query when `u1.strange['whyisthisdifferent']` returns the relationship signature? This reminds me of the Javascript difference between returning a function definition or a function literal, but this isn't Javascript.

I do believe that reading the [SQLAlchemy Association Proxy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) will actually get me what I want, but I would still like to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy uses metaclasses to construct models, which allows it to do all sorts of magic. When you declare the User class, it looks for attributes at the top level which are columns, relationships etc. and changes them to something different. You can check and find that `isinstance(User.id, db.Column)` is false. But it doesn't pick up these objects inside something else like a dictionary.

Comment: "looks for attributes at the top level which are columns, relationships etc. and changes them to something different" + "But it doesn't pick up these objects inside something else like a dictionary." 
This is exactly what I needed to hear and answers the question. Can you point me to where I could read about explicitly forcing the model to recognize relationships arbitrarily deep? I'd _really_ like to keep my sizes organized in a dict like this.

Comment: @Lirum I'm not sure if it's possible, but this looks like a promising place to start: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html